# root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

When I create a scaffold in terminal, I get the above error message.  I have type the following command first:

```
echo "source \$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
```

I still get the following error:

```
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'

The program 'rails' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ruby-railties
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not nearly enough information to help. What's your OS? What login are you using?

Comment: @MarsAtomic Ubuntu 16.04; As a regular user, I am trying to generate a scaffold.  ROR is running on another terminal.  Do you need any additional info, please let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the command `source ~/.bashrc` and then re-running rails. If that doesn't work, a different approach may be needed.

The problem is that as far as your OS is concerned, Rails doesn't exist. There could be multiple reasons for this. Seeing that you're using rvm, rvm is supposed to tell Ubuntu where to find rails.

Make sure that you are using the correct version of ruby specified in your Gemfile by typing `rvm current`. Make sure you are using the correct version when running `bundle install`, otherwise the gems will be installed under a different ruby version.

Also, make sure that the `~/.rvm` directory exists and that the path specified in your `.bashrc` file is correct.

Let me know if any of these suggestions help.

Comment: Rails are running on another terminal alright.  But, the second terminal is the one that's not taking the commands.  I tried your suggestion: source ~/.bashrc.  No response.  I still get the same error.

Comment: I have attached the bash.bashrc file for your review.  I don't see the path for .rvm in '.bashrc' file.  I hope I am looking at the right file.   I tried 'rvm current', too. I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you install rvm as described at `https://rvm.io/`? I've seen many instructions for installing rubies and gems, but I find this source to be the most comprehensive, even for Rails.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  You know, as you mentioned before, this is Ubuntu issue.  I went ahead and updated the system and restarted it.  Now, it works fine.  Again, thank you for your time.